# Move object to a certain position with speed Unity (2D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 2 moving objects with basic movement in one direction:

```
if(CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 == false)
        {
            if(scoreNumber.scoreCounter >= 0 && scoreNumber.scoreCounter < 10){
                speed = 0.3f;
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * 1.7f, 0);
            }
}
```

On success, which is on click type of event, objects have to stop moving in that direction and return to a starting position in opposite direction having speed component a bit bigger than while they were moving in the beginning direction. On click event simply changes the boolean value of "CircleMovement1.switchMovement1" so that the objects can move in the opposite direction:

```
else if(CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 == true)
        {
            if(scoreNumber.scoreCounter >= 0 && scoreNumber.scoreCounter < 10){
                rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed * 25f, 0);
            }}
```

The problem is: once the objects reach the starting position again they have to stop and move forward again as if CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 == false as shown in the first snippet. I don't know how to mark a moment in which they reached the starting point and can begin to move in the opposite direction. I tried adding colliders and detect a collision with an object on the starting point:

```
public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "mainCol")
    {
        CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 = false;
    }
}
```

But that did not turn well because on higher speed objects sometimes penetrate through collider of the starting point and go backwards more than needed (it's not consistent).

I tried to track the local position of objects like this:

```
if(this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.x == 30) {
        CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 = false;
    }
```

but that didn't work at all.

And last, I tried to use Lerp function to move objects to a starting position like this:

```
circ3.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = new Vector3(Mathf.Lerp(currPos3.x,-1,1f * Time.deltaTime),2,0);
```

This works but not in the way I want it to work. It just instantly spawns an object in the given vector position and doesn't have the same look as movement with speed.

If anyone knows how to detect the point where objects reach the position that they need feel free to help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have shown this code. The x position will rarely or ever meet exactly 30 because because of how it is moving and it having decimal numbers. That is the reason why its not working.

```
if(this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition.x == 30) {
        CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 = false;
}
```

You could try checking its distance to the target position like this:

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition, targetPos);
if (distance < 1)
{
    CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried that now but it is very inconsistent, sometimes too long sometimes too short.

Comment: In your question you are talking about fast speeds. How fast are we talking about?

Comment: rb.velocity = new Vector2(0.3 * 1.7f, 0) -> this is not fast
rb.velocity = new Vector2(3.7 * 1.7f, 0) -> this is very fast
It's not like unbeliveably fast but it is enough for script not to be able to react on time if I use distance comparison method and colliders. I think I have to find a right way to use lerp or smthn.

Comment: What margins are we talking about? When I am testing with the above code the object is like 0.2 units away from its position. You can always set it's position manually to the desired point after reaching it to ensure that it is in the exact coordinats you want it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by the correct usage of Lerp function and I think this is the only way to achieve consistency and accuracy:

```
 void Update()
{
    if(callLerp==true){
        if(Vector3.Distance(circ1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition, circ2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition) > 3){
              circ1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(circ1.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition, new Vector3(-1,2,0), Time.deltaTime * 10f);
    circ2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(circ2.GetComponent<RectTransform>().localPosition, new Vector3(30,2,0), Time.deltaTime * 10f);
        }
        else{
            callLerp = false;
            CircleMovement1.switchMovement1 = false;
        } 
        
    }
}
```